# Define with 'k'?

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor

I have always wondered, when you define something such as a string (or anything for that matter), why do people put a 'k' ahead of the defined name?

e.g. `#define kHello = @"Hello"`

What's that 'k' all about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the 'k' is short for constant. (Don't ask me why it's a k.)

Comment: the convention I prefer is `ALL_CAPS`

Comment: @Dave I like `ALL_CAPS` too, but a disadvantage of it is that with the `k` convention you can just type `k` in Xcode and see all of the constants available.

Comment: Is that an advantage? Usually when you want a constant you want a specific one, not just to choose one at random from a really long list! (or, to put it another way, the name of the variable is more important than its type when you're trying to find it)

Comment: @Dave you might be looking for a constant but not know what it was called, in which case a list of constants could be very helpful.